# How can i put two different threads on a single service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

can someone give me the code example that shows how to use two different threads on a single service? i didnt find the way to do it in google, then i need a code example...

one waiting 5 seconds and the other waiting 60 seconds, with different code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t5 = new Thread(Runnable_that_waits_5_seconds);
Thread t60 = new Thread(Runnable_that_waits_60_seconds);
t5.start();
t60;start();
```

Now you just need to define your runnables.

Also, you should give your runnables a way to detect that they've been interrupted and terminate if they do, and interrupt each thread in your service's clean-up code.

Comment: my service should implement runnable with your implementation?

Comment: Your service doesn't have to implement runnable, you can just declare a runnable class (two of them). markf's example shows this aspect of things (and a scheduling technique; with my example you would need each thread to sleep first).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to create and run scheduled events, then set them up like this:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

final Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("TestStuff", "r1 ran at " + new Date());
    }
};

final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("TestStuff", "r2 ran " + new Date());
    }
};

scheduler.schedule(r1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduler.schedule(r2, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Note that the threads can't do anything on the UI, but you did mention a "single service", so i'm assuming you're doing all non-UI things anyway.